# pandas dataframe groupby a col if value present in the group by row assign the same to groups row or assign a max value from external and increment

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Input dataframe

```
max_value = 5
x_max = max_value
data = {

's_id' :['G1','','','','G2','G3','G3','G4','','',''],
'r_id' : [2,2,12,12,20,45,45,9,13,13,14],

}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df2
Out[159]: 
   s_id  r_id
0    G1     2
1           2
2          12
3          12
4    G2    20
5    G3    45
6    G3    45
7    G4     9
8          13
9          13
10         14
```

Output dataframe,

```
data = {

's_id' :['G1','G1','G6','G6','G2','G3','G3','G4','G7','G7','G8'],
'r_id' : [2,2,12,12,20,45,45,9,13,13,14],
}


df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df3

Out[160]: 
   s_id  r_id
0    G1     2
1    G1     2
2    G6    12
3    G6    12
4    G2    20
5    G3    45
6    G3    45
7    G4     9
8    G7    13
9    G7    13
10   G8    14
```

Need to group by r_id and populate the values for s_id based on r_id groups, eg r_id with group 2 should have  s_id with 'G1', 'G1' if the value is already present  need not do anything, for r_id 12 there is no value hence need to use a external max_value that is 5+1 =6 and hence G6, r_id 13 and 14 will have G7 and G8 id, Thanking you..

The S_id can be numeric also without the G, instead of G1 it can be 1 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can replace empty values to `NaN`s and replace all values if exist per groups by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), then get rows with missing values and repalce them by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) created by `enumerate` and `f-string`s:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df2['s_id'] = df2['s_id'].mask(df2['s_id'].eq(''))
df2['s_id'] = df2.groupby('r_id')['s_id'].transform('first')

s = df2.loc[df2['s_id'].isna(), 'r_id'].drop_duplicates()

d = {v: f'G{k}' for k, v in enumerate(s, max_value+1)}
print (d)
{12: 'G6', 13: 'G7', 14: 'G8'}

df2['s_id'] = df2['r_id'].map(d).fillna(df2['s_id'])
#alternative solution
#df2['s_id'] = df2['r_id'].replace(d)
print (df2)
   s_id  r_id
0    G1     2
1    G1     2
2    G6    12
3    G6    12
4    G2    20
5    G3    45
6    G3    45
7    G4     9
8    G7    13
9    G7    13
10   G8    14
```

Comment: what if i need not consider the group by (r_id), i simply needs to replace with the max_value if not present.. in s_id column

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham - Not sure if understand, is possible create new question?

Comment: Need to check if S_id is there, if present ,then don't assign a GroupId, (G?), Else assign a GroupID from the max_value

Comment: I have created another ticket, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177434/replace-by-incremental-values-into-a-pandas-dataframe-if-a-column-value-is-missi