# Replace by incremental values into a pandas data-frame if a column value is missing

Tags: pandas

Input dataframe:

```
max_value = 16
x_max = max_value
data = {

's_id' :['G1','','','','G2','G3','G3','G4','','','']    

}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df2
Out[365]: 
   s_id
0    G1
1      
2      
3      
4    G2
5    G3
6    G3
7    G4
8      
9      
10
```

Output dataframe:

```
    data = {

's_id' :['G1','G17','G18','G19','G2','G3','G3','G4','G20','G21','G22']    

}
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df3

Out[366]: 
   s_id
0    G1
1   G17
2   G18
3   G19
4    G2
5    G3
6    G3
7    G4
8   G20
9   G21
10  G22
```

I tried the following:
    df2['s_id'] = df2['s_id'].mask(df2['s_id'].eq(''))

```
s = df2[df2['s_id'].isna()].drop_duplicates()
```

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
d = {v: f'G{k}' for k, v in enumerate(s, x_max + 1)}
print (d)
```

How do I achieve the output data-frame, replace the values if it's empty S_ID with the max values from external variable. Check the values of s_id column replace with an incremental values from external variable. for eg: In s_id column after G1, It has to be G17 ie max_value +1,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is create `list` with same size like number of empty values with `range` and set values by mask to column with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

m = df2['s_id'].eq('')
v = [f'G{x}' for x in range(x_max+1, x_max + m.sum()+1)]
print (v)
['G17', 'G18', 'G19', 'G20', 'G21', 'G22']

df2.loc[m, 's_id'] = v
print (df2)
   s_id
0    G1
1   G17
2   G18
3   G19
4    G2
5    G3
6    G3
7    G4
8   G20
9   G21
10  G22
```

Solution from @Jon Clements, thank you:

```
df2['s_id'] = df2['s_id'].apply(lambda v, c=itertools.count(x_max + 1): v or f'G{next(c)}')
```

Comment: Thanking you again, Let me check this..what document do recommend as to go through to handle these kind of task, Still a master touch is required at times.

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham - Your tasks are not so trivial in my opinion, so hard find some good tutorials exactly for this

Comment: agreed with @jezrael this was a v.good solution for a tough problem, I've been coding for just over a year and would struggle immensely with this.

Comment: A bit obscure but throwing it out there anyway: `df2['s_id'].apply(lambda v, c=itertools.count(x_max + 1): v or f'G{next(c)}')`

Comment: Although - probably better to make a generator and then use a list-comp to overwrite the series: `fill_value = (f'G{c}' for c in itertools.count(x_max + 1)); df2['s_id'] = [v or next(fill_value) for v in df2['s_id']]`